# Powershell script to check several Python Installs versions and architecture

Tags: pdf, excel, windows, powershell, x86-64

I have this powershell script where I want to check for each installed python on my machine: it's version (e.g; 3.11.0) and architecture (32-bit or 64-bit). Basically, I start by issuing this command: `where.exe python`, which returns a list of all python executables that it finds on the machine. Then, for each executable path I run it with the argument: `-VV`, like this:

```
function Get-InstalledPythons{
    $InstalledPythons= (where.exe python) | Out-String
    return $InstalledPythons
}

if ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem) {
    Write-Host "64 bit architecture system. Checking for Python installation..."
    $InstalledPythons= Get-InstalledPythons
    Write-Host $InstalledPythons
    foreach ($pythonPath in $InstalledPythons -split "`n") {
        Write-Host $pythonPath
        if ($pythonPath -like "*WindowsApps*"){
            Write-Host "This is not a Python, skipping..."
        } else {

            $PythonVersion = (Start-Process -FilePath $pythonPath -ArgumentList "-VV" -NoNewWindow -PassThru).StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
            Write-Host "Python version for $pythonPath : $PythonVersion"
        }
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "32 bit architecture system. Checking for Python-32bit installation..."
}
```

When I run the script, I am able to print the version variable (which contains the Python version and Architecture). However, I receive this errors and I am not sure how to fix them:

```
E:\Anaconda3\python.exe
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\achohra\OneDrive - PSP Investments\Documents\ada_install_scripts\install_python.ps1:17 char:13
+             $PythonVersion = (Start-Process -FilePath $pythonPath -Ar ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

 : hon version for E:\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\achohra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\achohra\OneDrive - PSP Investments\Documents\ada_install_scripts\install_python.ps1:17 char:13
+             $PythonVersion = (Start-Process -FilePath $pythonPath -Ar ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

 : hon version for C:\Users\achohra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
C:\Users\achohra\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
This is not a Python, skipping...
```

I need assistance fixing these errors.

After that, I also want to split the output message: `Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]` to extract the version (3.9.12 in this example) and the architecture (64 bit).

My final goal is the following:

- Given the operating system architecture check result is 64-bit `if ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem) {` I want to first to check if the `Microsoft Excel` is installed or not. If yes, check its architecture (64 or 32 bit); and based on Excel's architecture, check if one Python with the same architecture is installed or not. For example if we find that Excel is 64-bit and all the installed Pythons are 32-bit, then we need to install a new Python-64bit. If no, install Excel with the same system architecture (64 bit in the if statement) and do the same previous check on Python. The goal here is to have Excel and Python using the same architecture.
- Now, if the operating system is 32-bit (else), then we just check for excel if installed or not (no need to check its architecture since 32-bit OS does not allow to install 64-bit software). Then, we install python32 if it is missing.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: The `where.exe` command will return the list of `python` executables (anything named python.<any of $Env:PATHEXT>) that it finds in a directory named in $Env:PATH. It will not return any python executable that is not in the PATH variable. I have 3 versions of Python and several more venv instances. None of them appear in the PATH variable.

Comment: is there a way to find all python executables; either installed in the PATH or not?

Comment: Will this produce what you want? `Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'Python.*Core Interpreter' } | Select-Object -Property Name,Version`

Answer (score 0):

In comments it was asked if all python executables can be found installed or not !

so the initial method of `where python` needs qualifications.

to find the default install try `where $path:python`
[image]

and most likely it is just a placeholder !!

```
>C:\Users\lez\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe /?
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

but for full system you need `where /r c:\ python.exe` and same for any other virtual drive that may be called by any application.

so in order to test those for version you may want to redirect to a listing.txt to run a get versions command.

```
where /r c:\ python > pythons.txt&& for /f %v in (pythons.txt) do @echo %v&&@%v -V
```

This way you will get error feedback and see exactly which ones may be executable

For example here only 2 are working.

```
c:\Users\lez\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
c:\Users\lez\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\python.exe
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
c:\Users\lez\Downloads\Apps\Graphics\Inkscape\App\Inkscape\bin\python.exe
Python 3.10.8
c:\Users\lez\Downloads\Apps\Graphics\Inkscape\App\Inkscape\lib\python3.10\venv\scripts\nt\python.exe
c:\Users\lez\Downloads\Apps\Office\LibreOffice\App\libreoffice\program\python.exe
Python 3.8.16
c:\Users\lez\Downloads\Apps\Office\LibreOffice\App\libreoffice\program\python-core-3.8.16\bin\python.exe
c:\Users\lez\Downloads\Apps\PDF\em36\WPLOConverter\program\python.exe
```

Now the major hurdle with all these methods are that python MUST be at runtime in the path otherwise the install is non executable due to dll hell
so neither of those 2 valid sets will work well

[image][image]

### Answer

On Windows only an MS installed OR single python.org version found in PATH environment is likely to work without a runtime environment installer as usually provided by application launchers such as Libre office or Inkscape.
The reason as described by Python.org is "You should not add python to path"

https://discuss.python.org/t/could-we-add-python-to-system-path-by-default/3067/4

> The real problem with modifying PATH is it enables (intentional or unintentional) DLL hijacking (see CVE-2020-8315 for example, which essentially requires a PATH modification to exploit). To fix this, we’d have to remove all the DLLs from the directory on PATH, which isn’t really feasible.

Thus in my Windows OS there is installed **NO ShockWaveFlash NO Silverlight NO JAVA & NO Python allowed**
However I do run apps that were not listed above that initialise Python at runtime, under very user controlled conditions.